# Sharing Memcache on Gae with Go and Java

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, go

Can I write to the memcache from Go and read it from Java (on appengine)?

From the memcache viewer it looks like the answer is no, since there are keys of type "Java string" and "Go string".  What about sharing []byte?

Are web-hooks and the data store the only ways of communicating between Java and Go on Appengine?

Thanks

Comment: Just consider how you are communicating with memcache from your Go and Java apps ..

Comment: +1 @alphazero. This appears to be a disingenuous way of sharing information.

Comment: I don't follow.  @alphanzero, The Item type in Go stores the Value as []byte,  shouldn't the Java app be able to read it? Maybe using low level api..  I haven't seen it documented that memcache isn't shared between versions (of different languages).

Comment: @NickSiderakis No, rather, it's a strange way of sharing information between a Go and Java app.

Comment: In memcache Java API, the keys and values are of type `Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your question, but you will find part of it in method makePbKey in [MemcacheSerialization.java](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheSerialization.java). That shows how Java takes an Object and makes a key out of it.

Likewise, in file appengine/memcache/memcache.go, you can see how AppEngine for Go makes a key out of Item.Key (type string). See GetMulti, where each key is converted from a string to a []byte via a simple cast.

So, the final answer to your question depends on you finding a path through both mkPbKey and GetMulti that results in the same key. It seems to me like if you give Java a key of type String, and it has length less than 250, and you remember to put "" before and after your keys in Go, it might work. (But reading mkPbKey makes me wonder how it reacts to a string which has 200 code points in it, all of which result in multi-byte encodings in UTF-8. Seems like it will produce a bigger key than they are expecting.)

Comment: You're right, using the quotes in the Go Key allows access to strings written by Java. Using the Memcache Viewer to create a Go entry with [key, value] of ["a", abc], it was possible to read it as a Java String using the [key] equal to [a]. I still have to test it in code, thanks.